# How do I make named directories permanent in zsh and how do I edit them. Also what is the best place to look for documentation.

Tags: zsh

I just installed zsh and oh-my-zsh and I would like to use the named directories feature, i.e.

```
% hash -d foo=/etc

% echo ~foo
/etc
```

However, when I restart my console, these settings are gone. How do I make them permanent?

How do I edit them if, say, I make a typeo when setting the "alias" name.

Where is the best place to look for documentation of zsh?

Is this it? http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh_toc.html

Comment: I don't use zsh, but I imagine you could put that in the .zshrc. If you make a typo while using the shell, you could delete the incorrect name, then run the corrected command.

Comment: Note that for ordinary shell variables (the zsh doc calls them "parameters") that begin with a / become named directories, so in the example, foo=/etc suffices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Set static named directories

Open up `~/.zshrc` in your favorite editor and add the hash commands one after one like you did in your example, e. g.

```
hash -d foo=/etc
hash -d zshdoc=/usr/share/doc/zsh-common
```

and so on. The file `.zshrc` in your home directory will be loaded every time you start zsh.

## Aliases

You can also put your alias definitions there, just the same way. However, it is more useful to put aliases in a separate file, e. g. `~/.zshaliases` and then source this file from `.zshrc`. So, add this to `.zshrc`:

```
. ~/.zshaliases
```

and then add your alias definitions to `~/.zshaliases` like this:

```
alias ll="ls -l"
alias la="ls -la"
```

These are just examples of course. The reason to put those aliases in a separate file is, that you can edit it with your favorite editor and then simply reload all aliases by issuing the command `. ~/.zshaliases`.

## Documentation

Personally I like most the `zshall` manual page which you can open by running the command `man zshall`. It is very complete.

Other good sources for zsh documentation are:

- http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh_toc.html
- http://www.zzapper.co.uk/zshtips.html
- http://www.zsh.org/cgi-bin/mla/wilma/users (mailing list archive, to look for specific solutions others have asked for already)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways: by editing `~/.zshrc` or by adding an alias in a separate file. The latter one is more recommended by ZSH creators.
[See the full "receipt" here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69024818/16446105)

Comment: Do you actually mean "receipt" - which is a bill for items purchased - or do you mean "recipe"? Also, why don't you just cross-post your answer here, instead of encouraging people to visit SO? See [Is cross-posting an answer to similar questions on different Stacks acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291501/280335)